# Unable to set suspend timeout

Tags: 14.04, gnome, suspend, power-management

At some point *Suspend when inactive* stopped working on my system.

It used to work, but now regardless whether I set it via **System Settings** or `dconf-editor`, `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout` goes back to 0 after several seconds.

`dconf watch /` shows after I set it to 5 min:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
```

300
and then:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
```

0
It seems that some daemon is setting it back, but I cannot figure out how to resolve it.

Using classic GNOME on Ubuntu 14.04 (if makes a difference).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my own cronjob does this. Removed it from crontab and it works fine now. LOL.